# Joomla 3 on custon component Administrator notify

Tags: joomla, notifications, components

If you write one article in front-end like Author, Joomla send one notification to Administrator that advice that one new article was wrote. My component have ACL and work well but I not found where I must put the email sender. I must do a plug-in, I not found this in content component. Thnaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thou can create a content plugin which hold into the onContentAfterSave() or onContentBeforeSave() methods.

http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_content_plugin